# Swift Reading From a text file

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to read from a text file in Swift, but for some reason nothing from the file is read. This is the code i have so far:

```
let location = NSString(string:"/Users/Home/Desktop/file.txt")
let fileContent = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: location as String, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(fileContent)
```

This is what i have in my text file

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

When i run this code in the playground it giving me "nil". Does anyone know why?

Comment: Hey @Satish, This is working for me.  I assume your username isn't `Home`

Comment: my username isn't home. I'm running this code in a playground. Is that why its giving me "nil"?

Comment: My username is james.  So I used `"/Users/james/Desktop/file.txt"`.  You're getting `nil` because the file path you provided is likely wrong.

Comment: Type `whoami` in terminal.  That'll print your username.  Then change your string to `"/Users/<username>/Desktop/file.txt"`

Comment: my username is Satish so my string is "/Users/Satish/Desktop/file.txt" and im still getting the same thing

Comment: It works if i run in a command line tool project. How would i make it work in a IOS Single View Application? I'm trying to make a app that would read the contents from a file and display it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your OS X system files from an iOS application. The simulator is a sandboxed app. Include the file as a resource to your Xcode project and access it via `NSBundle`:

```
let location = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("file", withExtension: "txt")!
let fileContent = try! String(contentsOfURL: location)
```